# Possible to alter content of a remote page within an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

Can you manipulate content of a page from different website within an **iframe** on you own website page?

So, for example, I want to omit the navigation links and comments of a blog but keep the actual content, footer and banner of the original webpage owner.

Comment: nope, not really possible unless they give you some sort of api specifically to do this.  Generally, you cannot communicate in frames across different domains; and even on the same domain, its a bit complicated.

Answer (score 1):

In [supporting browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=postMessage), this is possible via [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) (covered by the [Web Messaging Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/)) but requires the co-operation of the site being framed.

You cannot freely access the DOM of third party websites as this would be a serious security risk (for example: Alice visits Mallory's site. Mallory puts Bob's site in an iframe. Alice's browser auto-fills the username and password fields. Mallory reads them with JavaScript and sends them to her own server.)